# No logro imprimir por pantalla el array de string

Tags: c++, array, punteros

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
const int NUM = 3;

void hola(string &mana[])
{

    mana[0] = "Hola soy sergio";
    mana[1] = "Mamam me quierre";
    mana[2] = "Hola como estas";
}


int main()
{

    string mana[NUM];

    hola(mana);
    string *p = mana;


    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        cout << *p++ << endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

En este codigo quiero imprimir con el puntero las 3 oraciones por pantalla pero por alguna razón me sale un error donde dice que no he definido mi array dentro de la funcion, pero yo lo mando como un parametro de referencia y aun asi no acepta mi array.

¿Cual es mi problem en este codigo. Muchas Gracias por su ayuda.?

Comment: Quita el `&` en el parametro de la función hola

Comment: Yo lo pasaba como parámetro porque creía que perdería su valor asignado en la función hola al necesitarlo de nuevo en el main. Pero es verdad logre compilar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla Agrega tu comentario como una respuesta para que el OP y los futuros entusiastas que busquen esta pregunta puedan dar con una solucion

Comment: Tienes razón, ya lo hago

Answer (score 4):

> Yo lo mando como un parametro de referencia y aun asi no acepta mi array.

No has acertado con la sintaxis de referencia a arreglo (array), tu código:

```
string &mana[]
```

Significa "*Arreglo de referencias a objetos* `string`", lo cuál no va a compilar porque C++ no permite arreglos de referencias. Si lo que querías era una referencia a arreglo de objetos `string` la sintaxis correcta es:

```
string (&mana)[]
```

Pero esto tampoco está permitido en C++. Es obligatorio indicar el tamaño del arreglo en las referencias a arreglos de objetos, así que la sintaxis correcta sería:

```
string (&mana)[NUM]
```

Esto funcionará siempre y cuando `NUM` sea un valor calculable en tiempo de ejecución. Con los cambios adecuados, tu código compila sin errores y se ejecuta sin fallos, puedes verlo <kbd>[aquí](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/hCvkfMf5NzjQhJWR)</kbd>:

```
using namespace std;
const int NUM = 3;

void hola(string (&mana)[NUM])
{
    mana[0] = "Hola soy sergio";
    mana[1] = "Mamam me quierre";
    mana[2] = "Hola como estas";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema está en:

```
void hola(string &mana[])
```

Debido a que se está pasando un puntero `hola(mana);`, se debe declarar un parámetro en la función de tipo puntero a string:

```
void hola(string mana[])
```

Lo cual es utilizar notación de arreglos, y que es equivalente a:

```
void hola(string *mana)
```

En notación de punteros.

---

Adicionalmente, también se puede definir la función con notación de punteros y no de arreglos:

```
void hola(string *mana)
{
    *(mana+0) = "Hola soy sergio";
    *(mana+1) = "Mamam me quierre";
    *(mana+2) = "Hola como estas";
}
```

Y la salida sigue siendo:

> Hola soy sergio
>   Mamam me quierre
>   Hola como estas